# having trouble with styling of a row of Bootstrap and alignment

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

In this section, some images are going out of their sections, and the background of the section is an image which is not properly shown.

```
<header class=" container-fluid"> 
  <!--<div class="clearfix"></div>-->
  <div class="container inr-header">
    <div class="header-top container">
      <div class="logo">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/logo.jpg" alt=""></a>
      </div>
        <nav class="top-nav">
          <a href="#" class="nav-tabs">Home</a>
            <a href="#" class="nav-tabs">HOW MOGO STACKS</a>
            <a href="#" class="nav-tabs">PRICING</a>
            <a href="#" class="nav-tabs">BLOG</a>
            <a href="#" class="nav-tabs">EVENTS</a>
            <a href="#" class="nav-tabs">SUPPORT</a>
            <a href="#" class="nav-tabs">CONTACT</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="slider ">
      <div class="slider-left ">
          <h2>The Mobile First <span>CRM Platform</span></h2>
            <p> MOGO CRM is a mobile first CRM platform that gives complete  CRM functionality such as Sales, Service, Time Management, Purchase Requisitions etc. to users on their mobile devices. Connect your  choice of smartphones with any backend system
            </p>
            <div class="brands">
              <img src="images/G-Play-Store.png">
                <img src="images/i-Store.png">
            </div>
            <div class="slider-btns">
              <a href="#" class="slider-btn btn-default SignUp">SIGN UP</a>
                <a href="#" class="slider-btn btn-default Demo">DEMO</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-dots">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/slider-circle.png" class="dots"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/slider-dots.png" class="dots"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/slider-dots.png" class="dots"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/slider-dots.png" class="dots"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-right">
          <img src="images/slider-image.png">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is because you did not follow the standard behind bootstrap grid system. in order for grid to work properly you have to use `.row` exactly after `.container` or `.container-fluid`. according to the official documentation `container`s can not be nested. and `.col-` columns classes must com directly after using `.row`. so there is always `.container > .row > .col-*` or `.container-fluid > .row > .col-*` sequence.

#### Read [Official Grid Document](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Comment: You're welcome, if that helped you, please accept the answer.